# Javascript: How to Dynamically Update My Closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JS so, apologies if this is a dumb question:

**Objective:** Each time the user selects a car from the drop down menu the price of the car increments a running total.

I have a JSFiddle of the code here: [Update a Closure](https://jsfiddle.net/vincej/swm18dvd/)

```
  <select id="select">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="100.00">Volvo</option>
  <option value="200.00">Saab</option>
  <option value="300.00">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="400.00">Audi</option>
</select>

<p>total:</p>
<p id="total"> </p>
```

Javascript:

```
var addTo = function(passed) {

  var add = function(inner) {
    return parseInt(passed) + parseInt(inner);
  }

  return add
};

var inner = 0; // Need to Dynamically be able to Update this value so that it increments with each new car selected

var addProd = new addTo(inner);

$("#select").change(function() {
  var car = $("#select").val();

  $("#total").append(addProd(car));
});
```

So, I grab the selected product. The closure then adds the product  price to zero to start.

I select another car. This second car price must be added to the first, thus incrementing the total. It is the total which is displayed on the webpage.

Sounds like it should be easy. The code in the Fiddle does not work. I do not know how to get the code to increment the "inner" value of the closure. Obviously it is the inner which must persist between each selection.

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting closures? For instance why not just increment the `inner` variable in the change event?

Comment: Why are you using parseInt() in your add function? The inner value is already a number, and the prices in your drop-down list have decimal places so parseFloat() would make more sense for them (though in practice of course for the values you've shown the decimal places/cents are just zeros).

Comment: @PatrickEvans - I'll give that a try. I had believed that in order to persist a value it had to be in a closure. Still learning JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
var runningTotal = 0;

$("#select").on('change', function() {
  var car = parseInt($(this).val());
  runningTotal += car;

  $("#total").html(runningTotal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable inside the closure to hold the running total.

```
var addTo = function(passed) {
  var total = parseInt(passed);
  var add = function(inner) {
    total += parseInt(inner);
    return total;
  }

  return add;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this situation would best use an IFFE

```
var carTotal = (function() {
  var total = 0;

  return {
    addToTotal: function(val) {
      total += val;
      return total;
    }
  };
})();

$("#select").change(function() {
  var car = $("#select").val();

  $("#total").append(carTotal.addToTotal(car));
});
```

Comment: You've got a typo, it's IIFE* :)

Comment: And for future visitors, what the heck is an IIFE?

Comment: @JoaquínO Thanks for that - still learning: what is an IFFE ?

Comment: Oh, the answer's not mine.. I just pointed out the typo. Anyway, an IIFE (Immediate-Invoked Function Expresion) is a function that's declared and immediately called. It's useful to generate a closure and avoid leaving a fingerprint in the global scope, and in your case provides you a scope which stores your total value. You can read a little more about IIFE here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression